# Python: How can add words to a list?

Tags: python, string, list, html-parsing, append

Okay, the Title is a bit vague, but what I'm trying to do is download data online, parse it and then put the parsed 'data' into an excel file.

I'm getting stuck in trying to put the data into a vector or list. Note that, the data can be either words or numbers. Also, I the length of the data is unknown. I tried the code below:

```
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_data(self, data):
        d=[]
        d=d.append(data)

parser = MyHTMLParser()
parser.feed('<html><head><title>Test</title></head>'
            '<body><h1>Parse me!</h1></body></html>')

d

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#34>", line 1, in <module>
d
NameError: name 'd' is not defined
```

I looked around the forum for an answer, but didn't seem to encounter anything. I am a beginner, so may I'm missing something basic? Thanks, for the help...

Comment: "I changed the <> to () for the html part" Please don't do that. Just format the code properly.

Comment: FYI `list.append()` returns `None`. So, you're assigning `None` to `d` in `MyHTMLParser`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three problems with your code.

- You are creating a new empty list every time you call the method.
- `list.append` returns `None` (not the list) so your list that now contains one element is not actually stored anywhere.
- Assigning to a variable inside a function creates a *local* variable, not a *global* variable (unless you specify that the variable should be global with the `global` keyword).

Try this instead:

```
d = []

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_data(self, data):
        d.append(data)
```

It's also a bad style to use global variable. You might want to consider making `d` an attribute of the class, and giving it a better name.

Comment: Hey thanks. This works great! But question, what's so bad about using global variables? I'm going to give it a better name after I get all the coding right.

Answer (score 4):

Inside of class methods, you need to use `self` to reference a member variable.

Starting with something like this might make more sense:

```
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        self.d = []
    def handle_data(self, data):
        self.d.append(data)
```

Then, to access `d` you would need to specify the class instance, so something like

```
parser.d
```

**EDIT:** `global` would work, but unless there is a compelling reason, I think you should learn how to do things the correct way rather than clutter the global namespace

Comment: Are you sure this code runes successfully? IMHO, you're __init__ ctor is incorrect, it lacks of line: HTMLParser.__init__(self)

Comment: @mloskot: This is exactly right, I didn't notice it was inheriting another class.  I'll edit it now

Comment: I didn't see all the comments listed before I started to post... so please disregard. Thanks.

Comment: Hey, firstly thanks for the help! But it seems like there still seems to be something wrong.   
 >>> class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
 def __init__(self):
  HTMLParser.__init__(self)
  self.d = []
  def handle_data(self, data):
   self.d.append(data)

   
>>> parser = MyHTMLParser()
>>> parser.feed('<html><head><title>Test</title></head>'
            '<body><h1>Parse me!</h1></body></html>')
>>> parser.d
[]
- d seems to be empty still.

Comment: I tried removing the self.d = [] line also, but then I get                                         Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#88>", line 1, in <module>
    parser.d
AttributeError: MyHTMLParser instance has no attribute 'd'

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bind a name at module scope then you need to use `global` on it at the beginning of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    data = []
    def get_data(self):
        return self.data
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        pass
    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        pass
    def handle_data(self, data):
        self.data.append(data)


# instantiate the parser and fed it some HTML
parser = MyHTMLParser()
parser.feed('<html><head><title>Test</title></head>'
            '<body><h1>Parse me!</h1></body></html>')
print 'All data', parser.get_data()
```

Output:

```
All data ['Test', 'Parse me!']
```

Comment: Hey thanks, this seems to be what I wanted to do. Mark Byer's answer is also right so I saw that first and went with it. Appreciate the help though thanks.